# Realm in AsyncDisplayKit causes Termination - realm::IncorrectThreadException

Tags: ios, swift, realm, asyncdisplaykit, realm-cocoa

I'm using `RealmSwift` with `AsyncDisplayKit`, I'm getting this error all the time from `ASDataController.mm`:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.
```

I have a `DataSourceManager` class that contains the data, and a `DatabaseManager` that handles the `fetch` and `insert` operations.

Exception always occurs in `_layoutNodesFromContexts:ofKind:completion:`.
I've tried any combination of GCD that I knew (Serial, Concurrent, Barrier), but I couldn't handle this exception.

How should I manage this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: so you tried `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()...` ? (just to make sure)

Comment: @Fonix I did, but `AsyncDisplayKit` doesn't do layout in `main_queue`. The mystery is that I down't know in which queue the `_layoutNodesFromContexts:ofKind:completion:` is running.

Comment: Temporary fixed by using CoreData!

Comment: This is the crazier temporary fix I've ever seen, just saying...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Unmanaged_RLMObject as workaround. Unmanaged_RLMObject is the RLMObject haven't add to RLMRealm.

It works, but I don't think it's good solution.

> Unmanaged instances of RLMObjects behave exactly as regular NSObject
>   subclasses, and are safe to pass across threads.

[Source](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `AsyncDisplayKit` (or `Texture` now) works on multiple background threads, and your realm objects are being passed around between threads. That's why the `IncorrectThreadException`.

To pass your realm objects between threads, use the `ThreadSafeReference`, along with using `realm.resolve` where you access your objects in AsyncDisplayKit.

[More info here.](https://blog.realm.io/obj-c-swift-2-2-thread-safe-reference-sort-properties-relationships/)

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy solution I have found is instead of accessing your data Model direct in they `layoutSpecThatFits` methods which are called in the background simply declare a parameter needed from the model and set it in your init method. Then use it in `layoutSpecThatFits` as usual.

For example:

Assume your data model is `Person`

```swift
class Person: Object {
@objc dynamic var name: String = ""
@objc dynamic var birthday: Date = Date()
}
```

In your node (CellNode, DisplayNode etc) on layoutSpecThatFit method don't access person direct instead have a property say `name` which you set it in `init` method, then use it like so: -

```swift
var name: String

init(person: Person){
// Set the property here so that you don't have to call person.name in layoutSpect method.
self.name = person.name 
super.init()
}

override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {

// Now you can safely use the param here on a different thread without issues.
if (self.name) {
// ---
}

}
```

Reference: [I found the idea from this article](https://programmersought.com/article/4766827469/)